# number of tokens in bash variable

Tags: bash, split

how can I know the number of tokens in a bash variable (whitespace-separated tokens) - or at least, wether it is one or there are more.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The $# expansion will tell you the number of elements in a variable / array. If you're working with a bash version greater than 2.05 or so you can:

```
VAR='some string with words'
VAR=( $VAR )
echo ${#VAR[@]}
```

This effectively splits the string into an array along whitespace (which is the default delimiter), and then counts the members of the array.

EDIT:

Of course, this recasts the variable as an array. If you don't want that, use a different variable name or recast the variable back into a string:

```
VAR="${VAR[*]}"
```

Comment: CAVEAT: If `$VAR` contains a string that happens to be a valid glob, the results will be unexpected, as pathname expansion will occur; try `VAR='* string with words'`.

Comment: What the heck. Please use `VAR=( "${VAR[@]}" )` which preserves the connections between elements like `"a b"` and `"a" "b"`.

Answer (score 34):

I can't understand why people are using those overcomplicated bashisms all the time. There's almost always a straight-forward, no-bashism solution.

```
howmany() { echo $#; }
myvar="I am your var"
howmany $myvar
```

This uses the tokenizer built-in to the shell, so there's no discrepancy.

Here's one related gotcha:

```
myvar='*'
echo $myvar
echo "$myvar"
set -f
echo $myvar
echo "$myvar"
```

Note that the solution from @guns using bash array has the same gotcha.

The following is a (supposedly) super-robust version to work around the gotcha:

```
howmany() ( set -f; set -- $1; echo $# )
```

If we want to avoid the subshell, things start to get ugly

```
howmany() {
    case $- in *f*) set -- $1;; *) set -f; set -- $1; set +f;; esac
    echo $#
}
```

These two must be used WITH quotes, e.g. `howmany "one two three"` returns `3`

Comment: Good one. Simple and no side effects (other than declaring a new function, of course). Plus, as a bonus you seem to have found a geshi(?) bash renderer bug.

Comment: Why avoid the subshell? Just efficiency? Incidentally, I had no idea that you can omit the `{...}` if you enclose your function body in `(..)` to run in a subshell - good to know.

Comment: @mklement0: Yes, just efficency. So it's an unnecessary optimization as the only usecase of howmany is probably debugging.

Comment: @mklement0: Yes, being able to just write `myfun() ( ... )` is kinda nice, but I feel it's somewhat inconsistent that bare `myfun() cmd args;` isn't allowed. Another note, it's also possible to declare `myfun() { ... } > "$foo"` (also with round parens) for call-time redirection, which is fancy.

Comment: @JoSo: Good to know about the call-time redirection feature, thanks; I wonder how useful it is.

Comment: I know we are not talking about "exotic" shells, but in ZSH, this seems to give me the line count. E.g., the example prints `1`

Comment: @Olsgaard I don't use `zsh` but if it works anything like `sh` then there is nothing like a "line count" in it. I assume gave it only one argument. How did you call the function? Did you happen to enclose everything in quotes?

Comment: how about:

howmany() {
    ( set -f; set -- $1; echo $# )
}

Answer (score 14):

```
set VAR='hello world'
echo $VAR | wc -w
```

here is how you can check.

```
if [ `echo $VAR | wc -w` -gt 1 ] 
then
    echo "Hello"
fi
```

Comment: Nice, but I suggest you (a) double-quote `$VAR`, otherwise the value will be subject to pathname expansion and (b) use current bash features; i.e.: - store the count in a variable (trimming whitespace): `count=$(( $(wc -w <<<"$VAR") ))`; - act, if the count is > 1: `if (( $(wc -w <<<"$VAR") > 1 )); then echo "HELLO"; fi`

Answer (score 1):

Simple method:

```
$ VAR="a b c d"
$ set $VAR
$ echo $#
4
```

Comment: 2 problems: (a) As in the accepted answer, a token in `$VAR` that happens to be a valid glob (e.g., `*`), will be expanded to the matching filenames. (b) If the first (one or several) token(s) happen to be valid `set` option(s) - e.g. VAR="-e" -, they will be interpreted as such and lead to unexpected results; you can prevent this with `set -- $VAR`.

Answer (score 1):

To count:

```
sentence="This is a sentence, please count the words in me."
words="${sentence//[^\ ]} "
echo ${#words}
```

To check:

```
sentence1="Two words"
sentence2="One"
[[ "$sentence1" =~ [\ ] ]] && echo "sentence1 has more than one word"
[[ "$sentence2" =~ [\ ] ]] && echo "sentence2 has more than one word"
```

Comment: This assumes regular spacing, i.e. two words with two spaces between them will give the wrong result (and the results are off by one here anyway -- fencepost error).

Answer (score 1):

For a robust, *portable* `sh` solution, see [@JoSo's functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11917591/45375) using `set -f`.

(Simple bash-only solution for answering (only) the "Is there at least 1 whitespace?" question; note: will also match leading and trailing whitespace, unlike the `awk` solution below:

```
 [[ $v =~ [[:space:]] ]] && echo "\$v has at least 1 whitespace char."
```

)

Here's a robust `awk`-based bash solution (less efficient due to invocation of an external utility, but probably won't matter in many real-world scenarios):

```
# Functions - pass in a quoted variable reference as the only argument.
# Takes advantage of `awk` splitting each input line into individual tokens by
# whitespace; `NF` represents the number of tokens.
# `-v RS=$'\3'` ensures that even multiline input is treated as a single input 
# string.
countTokens() { awk -v RS=$'\3' '{print NF}' <<<"$1"; }
hasMultipleTokens() { awk -v RS=$'\3' '{if(NF>1) ec=0; else ec=1; exit ec}' <<<"$1"; }

# Example: Note the use of glob `*` to demonstrate that it is not 
# accidentally expanded.
v='I am *'

echo "\$v has $(countTokens "$v") token(s)."

if hasMultipleTokens "$v"; then
  echo "\$v has multiple tokens."
else
  echo "\$v has just 1 token."
fi
```

Comment: You can also achieve `hasMultipleTokens` by case-matching. If you consider whitespace to be the default (space,tab,newline, or 0x20,0x09,0x10), try `case $1 in *' '*|*'<tab>'*|*'<nl>'*) echo yes;; esac`. Replace `<tab>` and `<nl>` by a real tab and a real newline, I can't put these in a a comment.

Comment: @JoSo: Cool, thanks. There actually is a way to create such chars. in bash via non-literals: `$'\t'` and `$'\n'`.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is exactly what you meant but:

`$#` = Number of arguments passed to the bash script

Otherwise you might be looking for something like [`man wc`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?wc)

Comment: redundant and not answering the specific question