# Get the executed command, quoted params, after executing `"${argv[@]}"`

Tags: linux, bash, shell

This function works:

```
source foo.bash && foo -n "a b c.txt"
```

The problem is, no matter what I've tried, I couldn't get the last line `echo "$CMD"` (or `echo $CMD`) to generate exactly this output:

```
cat -n "a b c.txt"
```

How to achieve that?

```
# foo.bash
function foo() {
    local argv=("$@");
    local OUT=`cat "${argv[@]}"`
    local CMD=`echo cat "${argv[@]}"`
    echo "--------------------------"
    echo "$OUT"
    echo "--------------------------"
    echo "$CMD"
}
```

The output is instead:

```
cat -n a b c.txt
```

With this command: `foo -n \"a b c.txt\"` it does work for the display of the command, but it gives errors for the execution via the backtick.

The file `"a b c.txt"` is a valid, small, text file.

Comment: I provided an answer, but I hope you don't plan on calling eval with that output.

Comment: I am not sure if that is possible, when you said `foo -n "a b c.txt"` bash treated the arguments as `-n` & `a b c.txt` removing the quotes & preserving the spaces. In case of `foo -n \"a b c.txt\"` the arguments were `-n`, `"a`, `b` & `c.txt"`. I am not sure if you can do what you are trying to i.e. make bash preserve quotes whereas the default behavior happens to be that of stripping. Maybe `IFS` magic ... or something else. Nothing I can think of right away

Comment: @another.anon.coward Yeah, but it does work for `local OUT=\`cat "${argv[@]}"\``, if it wouldn't be possible, it shouldn't work for that one either. Right?

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't quite get that. `OUT` will have contain the output of `cat -n a b c.txt` where `a b c.txt` is a valid file else it wont contain anything as missing file will be displayed on `stderr` which wont be save in `OUT`.

Comment: Just to clarify the filename contains `"`s?

Comment: The filename is exactly this: `a b c.txt`, so users may want to quote it when they pass it to commands, like this: `"a b c.txt"`. It's not just about filenames, this is just an example. It's actually a `git` wrapper, not `cat`, so the users usually type in textual comments, messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go, with the help of [number of tokens in bash variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638802/number-of-tokens-in-bash-variable) I've come up with the right solution.

I've almost forgot **WHY** we actually need quoting for **one** argument, it's because it has multiple words!

```
function foo() {
    local argv=( "$@" );
    local OUT=`cat "${argv[@]}"`
    echo "--------------------------"
    echo "$OUT"
    echo "--------------------------"
    local CMD="cat"
    for word in "${argv[@]}"; do
        words="${word//[^\ ]} "
        if [[ ${#words} > 1 ]]; then
            local CMD="$CMD \"${word}\""
        else
            local CMD="$CMD $word"
        fi
    done
    echo "$CMD"
}
```

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape quotes inside of the assignment:

```
local CMD="cat \"${argv[@]}\""
```

Also, echo is not needed to concatenate strings.

Comment: That gives `cat "-n a b c.txt"`, which is also not what I'd expect. Please note that the presented code is just a PoC, there could be any any flags (the command is `git` actually). I would expect exactly the same thing as typed: `cat -n "a b c.txt"`.

Comment: @Flavius - The quotes are never actually passed the function being called.