# How to count the number of words in a string in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the following string which contains words separated by spaces

```
str="word1 word2 word3"
```

How to count the number of words?

I do not want to use a for loop with counter. I want to do it in one command.

Comment: Isn't this a trivial question ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/638802/3076724 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/15108229/3076724

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `wc`:

```
$ wc -w <<< "$str"
3
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
str='word1 word2 word3'
str=( $str )
echo ${#str[@]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
awk '{print NF}' <<< "$str"
3
```

Answer (score 0):

`wc -w` is better, here is another way:

```
 echo $str |tr " " "\n" |wc -l
```