# Making a new column based on information on other columns

Tags: bash, shell

I have 4 columns with different locations like this:

```
Ica Ica Ica Ica 
Lima Ayacucho Ayacucho Ayacucho 
Lima Lima Ayacucho Ayacucho 
Lima Ayacucho Puno Ica 
Lima Lima Ayacucho
Lima Ica Ayacucho Lima
```

Sometimes some locations are missing, like in the 5th row there isn't a location for the last column.

What I want to do is make a new column, that tells how many different locations there are per row. For instance, the first row has the same locations for all columns. So I would want to have a new column with the number 1 in it.

It should look something like this:

```
Ica Ica Ica Ica 1
Lima Ayacucho Ayacucho Ayacucho 2
Lima Lima Ayacucho Ayacucho 2
Lima Ayacucho Puno Ica 4
Lima Lima Ayacucho
Lima Ica Ayacucho Lima 3
```

Note that because the 5th row has a missing value, the last column, I don't want any number there.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: But the answer already made, solves my problem only when all my localities are different. If they all have the same name, I would want to have a number "1" in the new column and not a "4".

Comment: Sorry I marked as duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/638802/number-of-tokens-in-bash-variable now I see it wasn't accurate enough. Reopening.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant, but it does the job:

```
awk '{
  delete cols
  for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
    cols[$i]
  printf "%s%s\n", $0, NF == 4 ? " " length(cols) : ""
}' input-file.txt
```